# Pass everything exists before and after special char in php regex

Tags: php, regex

Hello this is my string

```
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything', '7' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '6', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '5' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
```

i want to use regex and get each line that `'2' => '5'` exists inside it.

some like this

data {everything before (`'2' => '5'`) everything after it}

my problem is how to pass everything exists before and after what i want (`'2' => '5'`)?

this is my regex. please fix it

```
data\h*[{](what should i use here to pass everything exists before)[']2[']\h*[=][>]\h*[']5['](what should i use here to pass everything exists after)[}]
```

Just get this lines

```
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything', '7' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '5' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
```

please fix my regex

**Thank your for your answers but there is one other problem .. if my string is**

```
data {'1' => 'anything
anynew line inside of 1', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything', '7' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '6', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '5' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
```

**(I use new line and everything else inside of `''` in lines) it will not get that line !!!!!!!!!!!!! what should i do for that? `.*` not work when i have several lines inside of each line** **i need to get everything (include lines and ...) before and after !!!**

Comment: but, what happens if there are multiple `'2'='5'`?

Comment: Have a try with this `.*'2' => '5'.*`

Comment: `Just get this lines` - Those are the only lines with 2=>5

Comment: This has some strange  `PHP`-array-functions-builtin-odour...

Comment: Do you need to use regex?

Comment: I think `split` (`explode`) can also do that

Comment: @nerdlyist - Regex is perfect for this. A single string with many lines? Covered `.*`. Embedded literal's, covered. Regex is the best solution.

Comment: @sln I was not saying that it is not but the issue with Regex is it is hard to read especially for a simple token like "'2' => '5'". I wanted to provide another option that is all. If the OP does not want it then I was not going to provide it.

Comment: @nerdlyist - _Hard to read?_ Make it readable -> _[here](http://www.regexformat.com)_

Comment: @sln 
$re = "/data {(.*)'2' => '5'(.*)}/m"; 

compared to 

$token = "'2' => '5'"

Comment: @nerdlyis - I guess you could find `'2' => '5'` literal in a string if that's all you're doing probably don't need regex. Formatting and using the _ignore whitespace_ option lets you view regex like c++ source code. Where the equivalent is `for(intk=6,j=(nCnt-1);j*k<nEOL;j+=(k-1)/2)` is hard to read, think I'll use JavaScript. More than likely, regex is hard to do, so is C++

Comment: @MyJustWorking: What if you just extract the `Data{}` strings and then check with `strpos` if they contain `'2' => '5'`? Are the `'2'` always digits and the next `''` just C strings?

Comment: i tried it .. not working for heavy process

Comment: @MyJustWorking: See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD7iB6/1), and this [IDEONE code demo](http://ideone.com/tkZghn)

Comment: its not what i want ... i want to get '2' => '5' directly and no strpos if i have 2 milion line like this, i have to get each and check each inside ... wow !

Comment: Here is a [kamikaze regex](https://regex101.com/r/jD7iB6/2).

Answer (score 0):

To capture one or more `'key' => 'value',` parts use this:

```
((\s*'[^']*'\s*=>\s*'[^']*'\s*,\s*)*)
```

But, you can check whether a line contents your string without a full-match pattern:

```php
preg_match("#'2' => '5'#", $line);
```

---

**Update:** If you want to capture multiline text, use a strictly matching pattern:

```php
$content = "data {'1' => 'anything
anynew line inside of 1', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything', '7' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '2' => '6', '3' => 'anything'}
data {'1' => 'anything', '5' => 'anything', '2' => '5', '3' => 'anything'}";

preg_match_all("#data\\s*\\{((\\s*'[^']*'\\s*=>\\s*'[^']*'\\s*,\\s*)*)\\s*'2'\\s*=>\\s*'5'\\s*((\\s*,\\s*'[^']*'\\s*=>\\s*'[^']*'\\s*)*)#", $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo "BEFORE: " . $match[1] . "<br />";
    echo "AFTER: " . $match[3] . "<br />";
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

---

**I note:** if you are who generate this data, you should use a better format. For example, *JSON streaming* is a good solution for multiline-content data structures. You can find a JSON stream parser for PHP easily.